Getting I/O Error: Socket Closed when attempting to open SQL connection
Simply trying to open a connection to a previously functional Msft SQL Server instance from an Android device and getting this error. We are leaning towards a network issue but reading about this error it seems that it can almost be caused by anything! The Android device and app work fine with other SQL Servers. Server or Network? We cannot seem to duplicate this error on our server for testing (disabling SQL, Remote Access, Shutting down server, etc.)
Thanks in advance

Please reconsider connecting directly to a database server from an Android app.

Run a wireshark trace on TDS packets and see where it dies perhaps
